# Android Push notifications and SSL

Tags: php, android, push-notification

Im desperate and would realy appreciate your help. I had a php script which sends FCM-Push notifications to my android application but unfortunately since i added a self signed SSl certificate to my server, my application always crash when i submit the request from my application. This is the method of how i submit push notifications:

Php:

```
$fields = array
(
'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
'data'          => $msg,
);
$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
 );



$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

If i outcomment the above code - everything works just fine but of course the application don't receive any push notfications anymore. Please help!

My LogCat in the applications says:

```
10-03 20:08:02.582 8870-8870/de.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: de.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx, PID: 8870
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getAdapter()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: can you post eror

Comment: In my application im using retrofit and recyclerview, the application fails in the onResponse method LogCat says: 10-03 20:08:02.582 8870-8870/de.weprove.retrorecycler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: de.weprove.retrorecycler, PID: 8870
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.getAdapter()' on a null object reference

Comment: you can verify php code by adding token

Comment: user token is valid, as i said, if i run this script on my other server which doesn't have ssl certificate it totaly works fine

Comment: okay.i dont have much idea about android

Comment: Thanks anyway - im realy desperate about this issue